# Automation tool for website testing

Tags: automated-testing

What are the automation tools for testing a website, which does load test, broken link test, Spelling check test and Compatibility test

Comment: When you searched for those tools on Google, what did you find?

Comment: Too broad. Do your homework first. What did you found so far? What is your situation? Did you read any reviews?

Comment: powermapper.com/products/sortsite Sortsite Performs all the above mentioned tests. But unable to perform load test.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=List+of+web+testing+tools

Comment: I meant only **websites** not webapplication

Comment: @PeterMasiar http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Difference+between+web+application+and+website

Comment: @RufusRobert - you can safely assume (i.e. from my profile)  that I do not need your help for that google query to find difference between website and web app. I don't know anything about you and your skills but the text of your question, and we get daily few of such low-quality questions. Feel free to show is your homework and we will be happy to help you more.

Comment: Replied for your google query which i haven't even asked

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial tools such as:

- testng http://testng.org/doc/
- ranorex https://www.ranorex.com/web-test-automation.html
- ghostinspector https://ghostinspector.com/
- gurock testrail http://www.gurock.com/testrail/software-testing-tools.l.html

There are open source tools, primarily Selenium based tools.

- The seleniumIDE - a browser (firefox only) plugin http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/
- There are open source frameworks that use 'selenium webdriver' that go with the following programming languages: Ruby, Java, Python and C++, PHP, Perl and Javascript.  For example Ruby has Rspec with Capybara for the selenium DSL part.  http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

For load testing jmeter is commonly used.

Broken links are often checked through tests which are written to check them, making sure that a 404 is not returned.  There are specific tools for this such as https://go.siteimprove.com/broken-link-checker-trial-ppc-en and open source tools such as https://validator.w3.org/checklink from W3C

Spelling is normally checked manually by internal processes.  There will not be regression tests for this.  So many words will be trade and product specific that it takes a lot of effort to maintain automated spelling checkers for it.

Compatability of devices, browsers and versions is usually a fairly manual process.  What is right for a company will depend on many company factors.

Comment: https://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/ Sortsite performs spelling check, broken link test and  compatibility test. So **except load test** it does the above. I meant only **website / webpage**. I guess your answer was for web application

Comment: My answer is for web pages and web sites.  They may or may not be part of an application.